# how to extend rails form_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to extends the native form_for method to make it compile an extra input hidden.
I have already added extra custom fields to the form builder but I do not find a clean way to really extends form_for adding extra behaviour to it.

What I want to cleanly do know is this:

form_for ...... :my_custom_attribute => true

if my_custom_attribute is true form_for must generate an extra hidden field.

What is the most elegant way to achieve this behaviour?

I am on rails 3.1.

Answer (score 3):

I wrote a blog post on a similar topic, which might help you out : http://davidsulc.com/blog/2011/05/01/self-marking-required-fields-in-rails-3/

What you might want to try doing is

1. Create a file in (e.g.) `config/initializers/form_builder.rb`
2. `alias :orig_form_for :form_for`
3. Define your `form_for` method to call the original, and adding extra fields when necessary (e.g. based on object class, or options)

You'll find a helpful guide to how FormBuilders work : http://code.alexreisner.com/articles/form-builders-in-rails.html

And an example of a custom FormBuilder : http://code.alexreisner.com/code/informant.html